# Percentage of change with 2 data slicers in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a scenario with two data slicers. The first data slicer filters data for one period, the second one for another period. By editing visual interactions I got this works at the same page.
Now I want to compare two resulting values (in this case, number of transactions, and find a percentage of change between two selected periods.

I duplicated data column so I have two date columns for each slicer and I calculated the next measures:

```
# of Transactions 1 = CALCULATE(COUNT(Report[ProductID]),DATESBETWEEN(Report[Date1],[Start Date 1],[Last Date 1]))
# of Transactions 2 = CALCULATE(COUNT(Report[ProductID]),DATESBETWEEN(Report[Date2],[Start Date 2],[Last Date 2]))
% Transaction Change = ([# of Transactions 1]/[# of Transactions 2]) - 1
```

The first 2 measures are accurate (# of Transactions 1 & 2), but % of change doesn't work.
If you look at the screenshot below, you'll see # od Transactions 1 = 1,990 and # of Transactions 2 = 2,787. I want to compare this 2 values now.

How can I solve this?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: How is it not working? What is the result you get and what is the answer you expect?

Comment: Yes, how does is not work? I would suggest instead of using two date columns using two Date tables, it would be much more performant on larger data sets and much easier to create measures against and easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create two measure for your date bounds:

```
Min Date :=
MIN ( 'Report'[Date] )
Max Date :=
MAX ( 'Report'[Date] )
```

Then create a date table using the following DAX, this will join to you 'Report' table on the primary date:

```
Dates :=
VAR MinDate = [Min Date]
VAR MaxDate = [Max Date]
VAR BaseCalendar =
    CALENDAR ( MinDate, MaxDate )
RETURN
    GENERATE (
        BaseCalendar,
        VAR BaseDate = [Date]
        VAR YearDate =
            YEAR ( BaseDate )
        VAR MonthNumber =
            MONTH ( BaseDate )
        VAR YrMonth =
            100 * YEAR ( BaseDate )
                + MONTH ( BaseDate )
        VAR Qtr =
            CONCATENATE ( "Q", CEILING ( MONTH ( BaseDate ) / 3, 1 ) )
        VAR YrMonthQtr =
            100 * YEAR ( BaseDate )
                + MONTH ( BaseDate )
                & CONCATENATE ( "Q", CEILING ( MONTH ( BaseDate ) / 3, 1 ) )
        VAR YrMonthQtrDay =
            100 * YEAR ( BaseDate )
                + MONTH ( BaseDate )
                & CONCATENATE ( "Q", CEILING ( MONTH ( BaseDate ) / 3, 1 ) )
                & DAY ( BaseDate )
        RETURN
            ROW (
                "Day", BaseDate,
                "Year", YearDate,
                "Month Number", MonthNumber,
                "Month", FORMAT ( BaseDate, "mmmm" ),
                "Year Month", FORMAT ( BaseDate, "mmm yy" ),
                "YrMonth", YrMonth,
                "Qtr", Qtr,
                "YrMonthQtr", YrMonthQtr,
                "YrMonthQtrday", YrMonthQtrDay
            )
    )
```

Now create another date table from which to compare, and join to your primary date table in 'Report' and ensure the relationship is inactive:

```
Compare Dates :=
ALLNOBLANKROW ( 'Dates' )
```

Now create the [# of transaction] measure; one for 'Dates' and another for 'Compare Dates' like so:

```
[# of Transaction 1] :=
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( Report[ProductID] )
)

[# of Transaction 2] :=
CALCULATE (
    [# of transaction 1],
    ALL ( 'Dates' ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Compare Dates'[Date], 'Report'[Date] )
)
```

Now Create the % Delta measure:

```
Transaction Change := CALCULATE(DIVIDE([# of Transactions 1],[# of Transactions 2]) - 1)
```

This should work like a charm and will work for any dates selected in your slicers, you will still need to associate your date slicers with your new date tables.

I hope this helps!!

Comment: This really works like a charm. Thank you so much!
I still don't understand why my solution (shown above) doesn't work. I'll attach tomorrow .pbix file, so you can have a look if you want.

Comment: @Laki I am glad it worked out for you! Send me the .pbix and I'll take a look. Have a great weekend!!

Comment: Thank you again. This is what I tried to do at the beginning as I explained in the post above but not successfully (pbix file is uploaded do GDrive):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IUJA4c9-HvD68FzUJfU7B5xhYtkDhI0u

Best